# Dealing with code that has been written but isn't yet needed

Tags: version-control

I wrote a class to do something, but then realised that it wasn't needed, as I could optimize existing code to get the speed of execution I needed, rather than integrating the new class in with existing code (which would have been more complicated). However, I'm unsure if my current solution will be fast enough when I've written the rest of the program, so I'd like to keep the unused class around somewhere. I don't want to just keep it in the main version of the source code, as it would just be unnecessary clutter, but I think there must be a neater solution than putting it in its own file away from the rest of the project and coming back to it if I later need it.

I'm new to using source control, so I'm not sure what to do there. Could I create a side branch with the class, and merge it into the main branch without later?

Comment: Which source control system are you using?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Git, but I would expect it to be fairly system-neutral.

Comment: It also depends upon the programming language. With C++ you could bracket the useless code with `#if 0` and `#endif`

Answer (score 2):

I would `git tag` the current HEAD with a name like `my-old-class` Then I'd delete the class and move on.

A branch makes sense if you are going to keep working on it. But you aren't. `git tag` functions more like a bookmark so you can always go back and find the version of the code that contained your class.

You could also just delete the class, and if you need it again search through the log for the commit.

Answer (score 0):

With git, the rm command don't delete the history of the file. So you can get your class back later without problems.